# How to fix [ZAP-BootstrapGUI] ERROR org.zaproxy.zap.GuiBootstrap - Unsupported option in ZAP Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, zap

I am a beginner in ZAP. I am getting below error while configuring ZAP in Jenkins Job.

```
[ZAP-BootstrapGUI] ERROR org.zaproxy.zap.GuiBootstrap  - Unsupported option '-daemon -host <IP> -port <port> -config api.key=<api_key> -installdir <Windows_path>.;
java.lang.Exception: Unsupported option '-daemon -host <IP> -port <port> -config api.key=<api_key> -installdir <Windows_path>.;
```

How to fix the above error.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ndVs.png)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of the options you have specified are being passed to ZAP as one single option, which ZAP does not understand. You will need to specify them so that ZAP treats them as separate options. Can you post a screenshot of your configuration, hiding any sensitive info?

Comment: I have added the screenshot of my configuration Simon. Thanks

Comment: Are you using the ZAP.exe binary? If so you'll need to switch to using zap.bat as the exe does not support the command line options.